# WooCommerce: Hide categories with no products in stock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show a list of WooCommerce categories but without categories which have no products in stock.

At the moment I'm using `get_categories` for that:

```
$args = array(
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'show_option_none' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 1,
    'parent' => $highest_ancestor,
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
);
$subcats = get_categories($args);
```

I know that the I could add a `meta_query` to the normal product loop. Like this:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => '_stock_status',
        'value' => 'instock'
    )
)
```

But there seems not to be any option like that for `get_categories`.
Is there any way to hide out of stock products in the categorie list?

Comment: this should help : https://chrisk.io/woocommerce-hide-categories-with-no-visible-products-in-the-product-category-widget/